# Why is energy-density the flow of time momentum in the time direction?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, momentum, time

I have been reading this essay by John Baez (https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0103044) that explains Einstein's Equations in an intuitive way. A small detail that I found interesting was the statement, "the flow of time momentum in the time direction is just the energy-density". Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Time momentum" is energy -- that is, energy is the time component of the momentum four vector. So the flow of time momentum in the time direction is the amount of energy "crossing" a three dimensional slice of spacetime with a fixed time coordinate. In other words, it is the density of the energy at that time.